# less: multiple filter conditions with AND

Tags: regular-expression, less, filter

How to specify multiple filter conditions connected with AND in less?

I would like to filter a log having lines do NOT contain "nat" but contains an IP address 192.168.1.1, like:

&/!nat && 192.168.1.1

However it does not work, the result is empty...

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am convinced *less* do not allow to display only lines with `192.168.1.1` but without `nat`.

- You can use `|` (or)
- `||`, `&` and `&&` do not exist
- You can only invert match for the whole expression (with `!` at the beginning), but `!` is not special after

An alternative is to use *sed* before *less*.

```
sed -n -e '/nat/ d' -e '/192\.168\.1\.1/ p' FILE | less
```

Answer (score 3):

Since version v569, [less](https://github.com/gwsw/less) can "stack" filters in order to "drill down" into a log file.

From the man page:

```
&pattern
              Display  only  lines which match the pattern; lines which do not
              match the pattern are not displayed.  If pattern  is  empty  (if
              you  type  &  immediately  followed  by ENTER), any filtering is
              turned off, and all lines are displayed.  While filtering is  in
              effect,  an  ampersand  is  displayed  at  the  beginning of the
              prompt, as a reminder that some lines in the file may be hidden.
              Multiple  &  commands  may  be entered, in which case only lines
              which match all of the patterns will be displayed.

              Certain characters are special as in the / command:

              ^N or !
                     Display only lines which do NOT match the pattern.

              ^R     Don't interpret regular expression  metacharacters;  that
                     is, do a simple textual comparison.
```

So here, you'd do: <kbd>&</kbd><kbd>!</kbd>`nat`<kbd>Enter</kbd> then <kbd>&</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd>`192.168.1.1`<kbd>Enter</kbd>, or to avoid matching `192.168.1.1` inside `192.168.1.123` for instance <kbd>&</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd>`\<192\.168\.1\.1\>`<kbd>Enter</kbd>.